# Soft deletes with append only database in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, google-bigquery, soft-delete

Using Ruby on Rails and an append only database (Google BigQuery), what is the best practice for soft deletes? The pattern I'm considering is to append a new row for each update/delete and only collect the most recent record. But I'm not sure of a clean way to do that with Active Record. Any other suggested patterns / best practices?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant, Active Record is a query interface for Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big Query is for analytics against massive datasets.
If this is your case - you can ignore slowness that will potentially be introduced by adding new update/delete rows and “keeping” historical rows.

In BigQuery it is quite simple to get most recent version of your row using  [window function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#windowfunctions).

For example, assuming "id" is the primary key defining record/row and "ts" is timestamp

```
SELECT <fields list> FROM (
  SELECT <fields list>, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ts DESC) AS num
  FROM YourTable
)
WHERE num = 1
```

If you need to do historical analysis using historical data – here we go – it is easy to make selection that will represent respective version of row on that time.

If you do not need historical versions you can periodically do cleaning – for this it is better to keep you data partitioned by day (or month or whatever lese dimantion better fits to be partitioned by in your case)
BigQuery have excellent support for querying partitioned tables - [Table wildcard functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#tablewildcardfunctions)

If you want to stick with BigQuery – this will be a good approach
I do recommend to explore it more

Answer (score 1):

There's two things to consider here. How authentic do you want your revision history, and how important is performance?

The quick and dirty way to do this is to save a JSON copy of your record to a history table. This is easy to do, but there's no guarantee that the data in this will be schema compatible with future versions of the table, that is, you may not be able to easily restore it.

Don't pollute your primary table with deleted or historical versions. That leads to nothing but trouble and makes querying brutally slow.

Comment: Would querying be slow even if rows are rarely deleted or updated?

Comment: It's slow since you need to test for deleted or revised in each and every query against the table regardless of how often it actually occurs. `SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id=1` becomes something like `SELECT * FROM pages WHERE instance_id=1 AND deleted_at IS NULL ORDER BY revised_at LIMIT 1`.